# Render raw image bytes to response body

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating an API that creates authorized API calls to Google's APIs, specifically [Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) for this question. My API is working fine and uses [Google's Node API](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to make the requests. When I fire off a request to [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) resource, I get back the following response:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "...",
 "name": "bookmobile.jpg",
 "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
```

I use the above response to determine the MIME type of the file I'm to display later. I then make a subsequent call to the same endpoint, but specifying `alt=media` as an option to download the file as specified in [Google's Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file). If I `console.log` or `res.send()` the response, I get the following output:

[image: image bytes]

Which we can see is the raw image bytes from the API call. How do I render these bytes to the response body properly? My code is as follows:

```
// DriveController.show
exports.show = async ({ query, params }, res) => {
  if (query.alt && query.alt.toLowerCase().trim() === 'media') {
    // Set to JSON as we need to get the content type of the resource
    query.alt = 'json'

    // Get the Files Resource object
    const options = createOptions(query, params.fileId)
    const filesResource = await Promise.fromCallback(cb => files.get(options, cb))

    // Grab the raw image bytes
    query.alt = 'media'
    await createAPIRequest(createOptions(query, params.fileId), 'get', res, filesResource)
  } else {
    await createAPIRequest(createOptions(query, params.fileId), 'get', res)
  }
}

async function createAPIRequest (options, method, res, filesResource = {}) {
  try {
    const response = await Promise.fromCallback(cb => files[method](options, cb))
    if (filesResource.hasOwnProperty('mimeType')) {
      // Render file resource to body here
    } else {
      res.json(response)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error)
  }
}
```

Searching through various answers here all seem to point to the following:

```
res.type(filesResource.mimeType)
const image = Buffer.from(response, 'binary')
fs.createReadStream(image).pipe(res)
```

But this kills my Express app with the following error:

`Error: Path must be a string without null bytes`

How would I go about rendering those raw image bytes to the response body properly?

Comment: Instead of `fs.createReadStream`, just do `res.send( image )`, or even better, `res.end( image )`.

Comment: @JulianGoacher I get back the following using `res.send`: http://i.imgur.com/e0lNDfG.png It looks like it's rendering, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Either call res.end() after the send, or just use `res.end( image )`.

Comment: Same thing. Although when I save the image, it gives me the correct format to save it with the correct extension. After saving it locally and trying to open it, I get an error saying that the image is damaged. This leaves me to believe that the raw image bytes are getting corrupted which explains the black screen I'm getting or something else.

Comment: How does the saved file compare the output you pasted at the top of the question? Is it the same length?

Comment: Same size: 100338. Mac's preview fails to open it, but Chrome can, but it's the same black image from before.

Comment: Difficult for me to say what exactly is going wrong without seeing every detail, but firstly, using res.end() to send the image is the correct thing to do. The question then is, assuming the file returned by the Goggle API is valid, where in the code is it being corrupted? I'd guess this is possibly an encoding issue, perhaps caused by the image contents being roundtripped from binary to string and back again, but I can't say where this might be happening with the info I have.

Comment: One thing - just looked at your code above again - you effectively call files.get(..) twice, so on this line `const response = await Promise.fromCallback(cb => files[method](options, cb))` isn't the response object essentially the same object as *filesResource*? So then on this line `const image = Buffer.from(response, 'binary')` - shouldn't you be using a property on the *response* object, and not converting the entire object to a binary buffer?

Comment: My guess it's being corrupted when I make the second API call and likey the roundabout trip from binary string and back again. Yes I make two calls with adjustments to the `options` object. I've created a sample repo with my current issue, hopefully this will help: https://github.com/ciscoo/express-drive-api

Comment: It would be tomorrow before I can run that project, but I was looking on the googleapis github repo and found this https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/618 - I *think* it describes the same problem you're having, they seem to suggest that the api returns the binary data as a string by default (which will obviously corrupt the image data). If you look at the very last comment on the thread, they suggest using an `encoding: null` option on the request - although it does seem to be with a different api call - but maybe worth trying?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Post the answer and I'll mark it so you can claim your points! `files[method](options, { encoding: null }, cb))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google API client returns binary data as a string by default, which will corrupt image data when it happens. (The issue is discussed on this thread: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/618). To fix, use the `encoding: null` option when requesting the file contents:

```
files[method](options, { encoding: null }, cb))
```